# How to write testcase for testing things like "30 days expire"?

Tags: unit-testing

I want to write some test cases for my web app, but stuck at some cases such as "This token should be expired in 30 days". Nobody likes to wait for 30 days before the tests finish.

There are also other cases regarding some scheduled events to happen, like "Send this email 2 weeks after the user sign up", "Generate a bill 2 days before next billing date", etc.

What suggestion do you have on writing such test cases? Or, is there another way of making sure that these functions work as precisely as designed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My approach when writing these tests is to define the expiration in milliseconds. That way you can easily write tests because your test environments can define an expiration of 1 ms. The production environment will obviously define the appropriate duration. Typically these can be set as config values or db values.

Comment: Agreed. You will realistically need different rules in Dev and QA than Production to be able to test these kind of cases.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have some code like

```
if(token.ExpirationDateTime > DateTime.Now)
{
  // do some job to expire
}
```

Usually I provide the classes with such logic with an injected field of type `Func<DateTime>`. For example

```
public class ExpirationManager
{
  private Func<DateTime> _nowProvider;

  public ExpirationManager(Func<DateTime> nowProvider)
  {
    _nowProvider = nowProvider;
  }
}
```

Then the expiration code looks like

```
if(token.ExpirationDateTime > _nowProvider())
{
  // do some job to expire
}
```

This way you can substitute the real current system time with whatever DataTime you want when doing tests (e.g. unit tests).

Answer (score 0):

Break the functionality down and test the individual steps.

Expiring an item after a certain time consists of putting the item somewhere with an expiration timestamp and another part of the program expiring items with an old timestamp. Accordingly, test that new items are inserted correctly with the correct timestamp, and that the expiration code correctly removes items that are 30 days or older. The item being inserted and removed does not have to be the same for the sake of the test.

The same applies to email being sent after a certain interval.